# What is a type field?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ .
Under the topic `Type Fields` My book states the following:

> To use the derived classes as more than a convenient shorthand in the declarations, we must solve the following problem:
> Given a pointer of type `Base*`, to which derived type does the object pointed really belongs? There are four fundamental solutions to the problem:
>
> 1. Ensure that only objects of single type are pointed to.
> 2. Place a type field in the base class for the functions to inspect.
> 3. Use `dynamic_cast`
> 4. Use virtual function

My question - What really is a type field and what is the problem, which the paragraph tries to solve?

Comment: `My book states` Could you share what book that is?

Comment: It is - "The C++ programming" by Bjarne stroustrup

Comment: type_fields is probably the thing you would invent if you didn't have a concept of virtual methods.  Imagine the base class had a single member that all the derived classes would set in their constructor to indicate which type the  base pointer really was.

Comment: At the English language level, a "type field" is a "field" (i.e., a data member) that designates the "type" of the actual object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the book is suggesting something like this:

```
struct FruitBase
{
protected:
    enum class EFruit
    {
        Apple,
        Plum,
    };

    FruitBase(EFruit type): type{type} {}
    
public:
    EFruit type;
    void prepare()
    {
        if(type == EFruit::Plum)
            extractSeed();
        else if (type == EFruit::Apple)
            peel();
    }
};

struct Apple: public FruitBase
{
    Apple() : FruitBase{EFruit::Apple} {}
};

struct Plum: public FruitBase
{
    Plum() : FruitBase{EFruit::Plum} {}
};
```

Now, `FruitBase::prepare` can do correct action based on what is the derived type.

Comment: Preferably `enum class`, but yes, this is right.

Answer (score 4):

It refers to having a `enum` variable (or something similar) in the base class, which each derived class sets to its own value.

Comment: And what about the Base*, - to which derived type does the object pointed to really belongs?

Comment: @IcanCode To determine that, you read the type field from it, and look and its value. Presumably per each derived class you'd have a unique enum constant.